# Using websockets with Apache

Tags: php, apache, websocket

I'm trying to leverage websockets using PHP.
In order to avoid firewall restrictions the websockets should use port 80.
However apache is already running on port 80 and AFAIK apache doesn't support websockets.

I found a 3rd party apache module:
http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/

But it's partly in Japanese and marked as experimental.

Is this my best bet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use port 8080 which is a commonly used port for web apps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brief tutorial to get you started with pywebsockets and Apache:
http://chemicaloliver.net/internet/getting-started-web-sockets-using-pywebsocket-mod_python-and-apache-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Add another IP to the server and bind the websocket app on that IP.

Recap.:

- IP1: Apache - port 80 (You will need to change Apache to bind only to
  this IP)
- IP2: websocket app - port 80

There you go.